# Identifying information about executable

Tags: c++, executable, decompiling

I have a Linux executable that seems to have been written in C++ using a GNU compiler, and in debug mode. I'd like to know if my conclusion is correct and what are my chances of decompiling it into something at least somewhat readable. Here's a few telltale snippets from the executable:

**Snippet 1**

```
</heap>
<malloc version="1">
nclears >= 3 Arena %d:
system bytes    = %10u
in use bytes    = %10u
Total (incl. mmap):
max mmap regions = %10u
```

**Snippet 2**

```
__gnu_cxx::__concurrence_lock_error
```

**Snippet 3**

```
ELF file ABI version invalid ◻ invalid ELF header ◻ ELF file OS ABI invalid
```

**Snippet 4**

```
GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5 ◻
GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu1) 4.4.5 20100909 (prerelease)
```

**Snippet 5**

```
_dl_debug_vdprintf    pid >= 0 && sizeof (pid_t) <= 4     
...
_dl_debug_initialize (0, args->nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT
```

The file is full of readable text like this (but most of it is still gibberish). I don't think you should find this kind of text in an executable compiled in release mode (then again, my knowledge on the matter is very limited). What decompiler should I try to use on this executable?

Comment: Those strings are just string literals in the program (except for the last one maybe). You will be able to read the strings that are used by the program in release or debug modes. Also, instead of trying  to determine whether or not you can decompile it, why not just try decompiling it?

Comment: @Seth I doubt it. I know what the program does and it has nothing to do with those strings; its interface is not even in English.

Comment: They would be strings referenced by the libraries, not the user of the libraries, so it doesn't matter what language the program is written in. Whether the libraries only use those strings in debug mode or both release and debug, I don't know.

Comment: @Seth Oh, I see. I grepped "debug" and found quite a lot of references (I pasted two into Snippet 5).

Comment: Just try decompiling it and see what you get, don't waste time figuring out what optimisation was on. You get what you get either way.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you put a breakpoint in main and run the executable??? if it is debug mode, you could see the full source code(if the source file is present in the same path). you could step in each step and see the function calls with exact arguments.

Comment: I would, if I knew how. :) But thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.